# Python 3.x: Error on pyodbc sql server connection "no attribute 'execute"

Tags: python, pyodbc, attributeerror

I keep getting the error: "'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'execute'" I originally thought the complaint was on the table value function in SQL Server, however, I see that the message points to "execute", so I don't think `refcur` has execute defined. Here's what my connection string looks like:

```
    conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                      "Server=myserver;"
                      "Database=mydatabase;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                      "autocommit=True;")

    refcur = conn.cursor
    sql = "exec myschema.mystoredproc @TVPobject=?"
    refcur.execute(sql,this_object)
```

I've attached the image to show what I see in intellisense for what's available. Does anyone know why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you aren't calling `cursor`, you're just returning a reference to that member function and storing it in `refcur`. In order to call it (and actually create a cursor), you need to add parenthesis:

```
refcur = conn.cursor()
# Here -------------^
```

Comment: Now this has to be the DUMBEST thing I've ever posted--but I was spending way too much time on it. I didn't even notice the missing parenthesis. I'll leave this posted. I'm sure I am not the only one that has spent (or will spend) time chasing this error for this very reason! :) @Mureinik, thanks so much!